# Unnecessary auto migrations on Django?

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-migrations

running python 3.6 and Django 3.1.7!

So I have a Django project with an app with models as the following:

```
class Department(models.Model_:
   name = models.CharField(max_length=255)

class Person(models.Model):
    first_name = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    last_name = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    department = models.ForeignKey(
        Department, related_name="department_members", on_delete=models.CASCADE
    )
```

When I run `makemigrations` I get this on `0001_initial.py`:

```
class Migration(migrations.Migration):

    initial = True

    operations = [
        migrations.CreateModel(
            name='Person',
            fields=[
                ('id', models.BigAutoField(auto_created=True, primary_key=True, serialize=False, verbose_name='ID')),
                ('first_name', models.CharField(max_length=255)),
                ('last_name', models.CharField(max_length=255)),
            ],
        ),
        migrations.CreateModel(
            name='Department',
            fields=[
                ('id', models.BigAutoField(auto_created=True, primary_key=True, serialize=False, verbose_name='ID')),
                ('name', models.CharField(max_length=255)),
            ],
        ),
        migrations.AddField(
            model_name='person',
            name='department',
            field=models.ForeignKey(on_delete=django.db.models.deletion.CASCADE, related_name='department_members', to='my_app.department'),
        ),
    ]
```

That is all fine and good but now I've been getting this red text:

```
Your models have changes that are not yet reflected in a migration, and so won't be applied.
```

```
Run 'manage.py makemigrations' to make new migrations, and then re-run 'manage.py migrate' to apply them.
```

When I run `makemigrations` again i get this as `0002_auto_20211111_1116.py`:

```
class Migration(migrations.Migration):

    dependencies = [
        ('my_app', '0001_initial'),
    ]

    operations = [
        migrations.AlterField(
            model_name='Department',
            name='id',
            field=models.AutoField(auto_created=True, primary_key=True, serialize=False, verbose_name='ID'),
        ),
        migrations.AlterField(
            model_name='Person',
            name='id',
            field=models.AutoField(auto_created=True, primary_key=True, serialize=False, verbose_name='ID'),
        ),
    ]
```

I haven't made changes to `models.py` and also I can't see a difference on the 'id' field that is being altered on the auto migration.

I could always leave 0002 on the folder and get on with my life but it has really been bugging me. What is giving Django the signal that something has been changed on my models? How to avoid having to create that second migration?

Thanks!

Comment: Did you upgrade the Django version in between?

Comment: God damn it, spot on! Had to downgrade from 3.2 to 3.1 because Silk wasn't compatible with 3.2

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It migrates the primary keys from `BigAutoField`s to `AutoField`s. Likely the reason for this is that since [django-3.2](/questions/tagged/django-3.2), the [**`DEFAULT_AUTO_FIELD`** setting [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/settings/#default-auto-field) is added to the settings. If you thus specified for that setting:

```
DEFAULT_AUTO_FIELD = 'django.db.models.BigAutoField'
```

Then Django will thus use a `BigAutoField`.

If you then migrated back to [django-3.1](/questions/tagged/django-3.1), then Django did not take the `DEFAULT_AUTO_FIELD` setting into account and will use the `AutoField`. Since you do not mention the primary key explicitly, this thus means that it assumes that you use an `AutoField`, and thus will migrate the fields to an `AutoField`.

If you do not want this, you can remove the migration file, and explicitly define the `id` fields with:

```
class Department(models.Model):
    id = models.BigAutoField(auto_created=True, primary_key=True, serialize=False, verbose_name='ID')
   name = models.CharField(max_length=255)

class Person(models.Model):
    id = models.BigAutoField(auto_created=True, primary_key=True, serialize=False, verbose_name='ID')
    first_name = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    last_name = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    department = models.ForeignKey(
        Department, related_name="department_members", on_delete=models.CASCADE
    )
```